# What is this Laotian mystery leaf?

Tags: food-identification, thai-cuisine, laotian-cuisine

In Luang Prabang, Laos, I was served this mystery herb on the side of a dish of green papaya salad (ຕຳຫມາກຫຸ່ງ *tam mak hung*, aka *som tam* on the Thai side of the border).

[image]

**What exactly is this?**  The flavor was quite strong and rather bitter.  Google Lens thinks it's either khat or asparagus, both of which are quite definitely wrong.

Comment: Leaves bring to mind legumes to me, but hard to say without an opened out version. Might also get a better answer if migrated to Biology SE.

Comment: Looks a bit like chamberbitter, but I'd be surprised if that's really what it is as it's somewhat toxic.

Comment: @bob1 looks like it is indeed a legume (at least according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is *Neptunia oleracea* (Water Mimosa).

The leaves are normally fanned out but collapse in when touched.

It is a vegetable "commonly eaten raw or stir-fried in Thailand"
https://www.tarladalal.com/glossary-water-mimosa-1481i

You can see the leaves aligning more here:
https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/3334636150

Apparently the roots are also used medicinally in Malaysia and Thailand for things such as headaches, earaches, and skin wounds.
https://pondinformer.com/water-mimosa-neptunia-oleracea/

Comment: https://www.canstockphoto.com/water-mimosa-36364232.html supposedly a stock photo of water mimosa in a salad. It looks exactly like the original photo except for the color. Nice find!

Comment: Bingo, I think you've found it!  The Lao name is the same as Thai: ຜັກກະເສດ *phak kachet*.

Comment: Good answer. I knew I had seen leaves looking like that before, but was failing to bring to mind where/when - it was on Mimosa pudica ("sensitive plant") after touching the leaves and seeing them collapse, results in almost exactly the same pattern and coiled shape.